# Installing Libreoffice Headless for 5.0.x in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, installation, libreoffice, centos7, file-conversion

I am installing libreoffice 5.0.x on server for daily conversion task. So I need only the headless component. I am following the below tutorial for the same but it installs the complete version. How can the headless version be install.

Source: http://www.tecmint.com/install-libreoffice-on-rhel-centos-fedora-debian-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headless is a mode, not a separate package.  Install the standard libreoffice package and then run with the `--headless` parameter.  For example:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf *.doc --headless
```

Apparently other people have had the same question:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/53173/libreoffice-444-and-the-headless-install/
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=53875

Comment: In libreoffice 4 we have a headless package without which unoconv doesn't run in headless mode.
Source: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libreoffice-headless

Comment: The page you linked to says that the package is for a plugin.  I interpret this to mean that you need to install the complete libreoffice package as well as the headless plugin package.  Have you done both?

Comment: Yes, I have installed both

Comment: Then what is your question?  I thought you were asking how to install them.

Comment: No, my question is, since I am running it on a hosted server so I don't want to install all the packages. I just went to install a stripped down version of libreoffice which can run in headless mode.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works.  For most systems there is just the main package.  For systems like CentOS there seems to be the main package plus the headless plugin.  Why would it be called a plugin if it is standalone.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)